# gtag.js cookie not being set

Tags: cookies, gtag.js

I have put the tracking code with my id on every page of website.
But upon checking for cookies, I can see no cookie is being set by gtag.js.
According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id , the js code should automatically set the cookie.

P.S.- I am using Google Analytics for the first time. Total Noob.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, gtag.js uses the _ga and _gid cookies to distinguish unique users, and uses the _gat cookie to throttle the request rate. More details about cookies you can see here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookie-usage

To check actual cookies, please use plugin like EditThisCookies (plugin to Chrome). 
To check your GA implementation, please use Google Tag Assistant (also plugin to Chrome). Tag Assistant will validate if your analytics is working or not.

There is a need of more details about your website and GA implementation. For example, do you implement GA via Tag Manager? What is your website address? etc. Without such details it is difficult to investigate your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I will certainly use the extensions and let you know.

Comment: Used the extension tag manager and figured the solution.
Thanks.